# How to fix ubuntu boot problem caused by previous linux installation

Tags: boot, grub, uefi

My Ubuntu 23.10 won't boot smoothly right after installation.  The laptop just drop into the "grub mini-bash" black screen.  Temporary cure is to press F8 on boot which instructs the BIOS to let me select a boot option, I then select "ubuntu" and it successfully boot into the login screen.

The problem is that the Ubuntu Installer did not remove boot loader of my previous installation, Linux Mint Debian Edition.  I didn't tell the installer to install Ubuntu alongside with debian, and LMDE was actually wiped.

I found the following dirs/files on the /boot partition:

```
# tree efi
efi
└── EFI
    ├── BOOT
    │   ├── BOOTX64.EFI
    │   ├── fbx64.efi
    │   └── mmx64.efi
    ├── debian
    │   ├── BOOTX64.CSV
    │   ├── fbx64.efi
    │   ├── grub.cfg
    │   ├── grubx64.efi
    │   ├── mmx64.efi
    │   └── shimx64.efi
    └── ubuntu
        ├── BOOTX64.CSV
        ├── grub.cfg
        ├── grubx64.efi
        ├── mmx64.efi
        └── shimx64.efi
```

How can I remove the old boot loader?  Also, If possible please point me the right direction to a linux boot loader installation/problem fix guide.  For example, I need to know:

1. What is the relationship between EFI (/boot/efi) and GRUB (/boot/grub), which one is called the "boot loader"?
2. Is it better to install boot loader on the MBR or the partition where "/" is mounted?
3. If I am left on the grub terminal, how do I rescue myself? (I searched for such rescue and found most solutions are used when you are successfully in the GUI anyway, for example: [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)).

Comment: With newer UEFI systems you still install grub to a drive like sda, not to a partition. And with UEFI, the MBR is not used for booting. A gpt protective MBR exists only for one partition table entry saying drive is gpt, so old MBR only tools do not try to repartitions drive. You need to remove UEFI boot entry & folder in ESP - efi system partition. Post link to Boot-Repair's summary report. Use efibootmgr to remove UEFI entry: https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader & from live installer mount ESP & delete folder.

Comment: @oldfred I cannot install boot-repair, the ppa does not work.  I will read the material you provide first.

Comment: @oldfred "With newer UEFI systems you still install grub to a drive like sda, not to a partition.". I disagree. It installs in the ESP partition/filesystem (and a possible UEFI boot entry), not anywhere else. See for example the 3rd note in 1.1 there: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB#Installation "You might note the absence of a device_path option (e.g.: /dev/sda) in the grub-install command. In fact any device_path provided will be ignored by the GRUB UEFI install script. Indeed, UEFI boot loaders do not use a MBR bootcode or partition boot sector at all."